# how to search data using "like" in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I typed a word "boat", so i need records that start with boat and also that contains "boat".but starting with "boat" must appear first

i tried following

```
Select   AsiccCodeId,AsiccDescription             
FROM     AsiccCodeMaster  c             
WHERE    c.AsiccDescription like 'boat%' or c.AsiccDescription like '%boat%'
```

and

```
select a.* from
(

 Select   AsiccCodeId,AsiccDescription             
 FROM     AsiccCodeMaster  c             
 WHERE c.IsActive = 1  and (GoodFor = 'M' or GoodFor = 'B')
 and c.AsiccDescription like 'Unmilled%'



 UNION

 Select   AsiccCodeId,AsiccDescription             
 FROM     AsiccCodeMaster  c             
 WHERE c.IsActive = 1  and (GoodFor = 'M' or GoodFor = 'B')
 and c.AsiccDescription like '%Unmilled%'



 )a
```

but it gives me

```
4137    Combustion Boats 
6360    Boat, Fibre
6361    Boat, Rubber - Motorized
6362    Boat, Wooden Canal Boats
6363    Boat, Wooden With Engine
6370    Wooden Boats Body Building
6374    Boat, Rowing / Sports
6375    Boat, Rubber - Nonmotorized
6376    Boat, Wooden Without Engine-Others
6379    Parts Of Ships, Boats Etc., N.E.C
6391    Ships, Boats & Other Vessels, N.E.C
6394    Ships, Boats & Other Vessels, N.E.C
```

i need records that starts with "boat" first and then records that contains "boat"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a CASE statement in an Order By clause

```
SELECT   AsiccCodeId,AsiccDescription             
FROM     AsiccCodeMaster  c             
WHERE    c.AsiccDescription like '%boat%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN c.AsiccDescription like 'boat%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, c.AsiccDescription
```

Since you want titles that start with 'boat' to appear first, the CASE statement will prioritize those first.  It looks at each record and, if the description starts with 'boat', assigns it a sort value of 0, otherwise it assigns it a sort value of 1.  ORDER BY sorts ascending by default, so it will put all the 0s (the ones that start with 'boat') before all the 1s (the remaining records)

Comment: thank you so much ,it worked, but can you elaborate what did you do with case?

Answer (score 3):

You need to give your results some ordering!

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       AsiccCodeId, AsiccDescription, Sequence = 1
    FROM AsiccCodeMaster  c             
    WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND (GoodFor = 'M' or GoodFor = 'B')
      AND c.AsiccDescription LIKE 'Boat%'    

    UNION

    SELECT 
       AsiccCodeId, AsiccDescription, Sequence = 2
    FROM AsiccCodeMaster  c             
    WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND (GoodFor = 'M' or GoodFor = 'B')
      AND c.AsiccDescription LIKE '%Boat%'    
) a
ORDER BY a.Sequence
```

Comment: Simple solutions are usually the best.

Comment: But it contains duplicates

Comment: Simply because the '%' matches 0 or more characters. There are other wildcard characters that can be used too.